# Visa Transaction simulation program in C++

Tags: c++, oop, transactions, linked-list

I am doing a data structure project and it is important to write my own  template linked list class implementation ,it is required that:
Each visa account can do a transaction using the visa card and the transaction is recorded in his account with date and amount of money due.

My steps :

1. make a list of accounts in the system.
2. each account has it's list of cards, as it is required issuing another visa card with different number but to the same account.
3. make for each visa a list of transactions.

My problem:

1. that the transactions made by the card not saved in the list of transactions that is defined in the card class.. you can check the function settrans to see how I implemented it . how can I fix that ?

2.The balance "The sum of all transactions" is not updated, which I need it later to let the user pay.

NOTE : The main is not completed and there is another data I need to do another functions not completed yet so no problem if you found excess paramters.
and I didn't put pre or post conditions yet.

the header file with all functions and classes :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
template<class T> class list;
class account;
class card;
class transaction;

//Node class
template<class T> class node
{
public:
    node() : data(0), next(NULL){} 
    T getdata() { return data; }
    node * getnext(){ return next; }
    void setnext(node * n) { next = n; }
    node(T v) : data(v), next(NULL) {}
    friend list < T >;

private:
    T data;
    node * next;
};

template<class T> class list
{
    node<T> * head;
public:
    list() : head(NULL){} 
    void add(T data)
    {
        node <T> *temp = new node<T>(data);
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;
    }
    void printaccounts();
    void printcards();
    void printtransactions();
    bool checkaccount(string n, string p);
    account getaccount(string n, string p);
    bool checkcard(int i, string p);
    card getcard(int i, string p);


};


//Transaction Class
class transaction
{
public:
    void pushtrans(int ch, int a, int cat, int m, int d, string co);
    void newtrans();
    int getcharge() { return charge; }
    int getage(){ return age; }
    string getcompany(){ return company; }
    int getcategory(){ return category; }

private:
    int charge;
    string company;
    int month;
    int day;
    int category;
    int age;

};

void transaction::pushtrans(int ch, int a, int cat, int m, int d, string co)
{
    charge = ch;
    age = a;
    category = cat;
    month = m;
    day = d;
    company = co;


}

//Card Class
class card
{
public:
    card();
    void pushcard(string p, int m, int d, int x);
    int getid(){ return id; }
    int getm(){ return month; }
    int getd(){ return day; }
    int getb(){ return balance; }
    void settrans();
    string getpassword(){ return password;}
    transaction gettransobj(){ return t; }
    list<transaction> getlist(){ return tl; }


private:
    int id =0;
    string password;
    int balance =0;
    int month;
    int day;
    list<transaction> tl;
    transaction t;

};


card::card()
{
    password = "";
    balance = 0;
    month = 0;
    day = 0;
}

void card::pushcard(string p, int m, int d, int x)
{

    password = p;
    month = m;
    day = d;
    id = x;

}

//Account Class
class account
{
public:
    void pushaccount(string n, string p);
    string getname(){ return name; }
    string getaccpassword() { return passwrod; }
    card getcard(){ return c; }
    list<card> getclist() { return cl; }
    void setcard();

private:
    string name;
    string passwrod;
    card c;
    list<card> cl;

};

void account::pushaccount(string n, string p)
{
    name = n;
    passwrod = p;
}

void account::setcard()
{
    string p; int m, d,x;
    cout << "\n _Please enter your Password: ";
    cin >> p;
    cout << "\n _Please enter the Month: ";
    cin >> m;
    cout << "\n _Please enter your Date: ";
    cin >> d;
    x = c.getid() + 1;
    cout << "Your ID is : " << x;
    c.pushcard(p, m, d, x);
    cl.add(c);
}

template<class T>
void list<T>:: printaccounts()
{
    cout << "The Accounts: \n";
    node <T> *temp = head;
    while (temp != nullptr)
    {
        cout << temp->data.getname() << endl;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

template<class T>
bool list<T>::checkaccount(string n, string p)
{
    bool c = false;
    node <T> * temp = head;
    while (temp != nullptr)
    {
        if (temp->data.getname() == n && temp->data.getaccpassword() == p)
        {
            c = true;
            return c;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return c;
}

template<class T>
account list<T>::getaccount(string n, string p)
{
    node <T> * temp = head;
    account a;
    while (temp != nullptr)
    {
        if (temp->data.getname() == n && temp->data.getaccpassword() == p)
        {
            a = temp->getdata();
            return a;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return a;

}

template<class T>
void list<T>::printcards()
{
    cout << "\nThe Cards: \n";
    node <T> *temp = head;
    while (temp != nullptr)
    {
        cout << temp->data.getid() << endl;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

}

template<class T>
bool list<T>::checkcard(int i, string p)

{
    bool c = false;
    node <T> * temp = head;
    while (temp != nullptr)
    {
        if (temp->data.getid() == i && temp->data.getpassword() == p)
        {
            c = true;
            return c;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return c;

}

template<class T>
card list<T>::getcard(int i, string p)
{
    node <T> * temp = head;
    card c;
    while (temp != nullptr)
    {
        if (temp->data.getid() == i && temp->data.getpassword() == p)
        {
            c = temp->getdata();
            return c;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return c;
}

void card::settrans()
{
    string s; int m, d,a,c,p;
    cout << "\n _Please enter charge: ";
    cin >> p;
    cout << "\n _Please enter the Month: ";
    cin >> m;
    cout << "\n _Please enter your Date: ";
    cin >> d;
    cout << "\n _Choose the Category: \n";
    cout << "|--------------|" << endl;
    cout << "| 1.Food       |" << endl;
    cout << "| 2.Clothes    |" << endl;
    cout << "| 3.Medicine   |" << endl;
    cout << "|--------------|" << endl;
    cin >> c;
    cout << "\n _Please enter the Company/Shop: ";
    cin >> s;
    cout << "\n _Please enter your age: ";
    cin >> a;
    balance += p;
    cout << "Balance = " << balance;
    t.pushtrans(p, a, c, m, d, s);
    tl.add(t);

}

template<class T>
void list<T>::printtransactions()
{
    int i = 1;
    cout << "\nThe Transactions: \n";
    node <T> *temp = head;
    while (temp != nullptr)
    {
        cout << i << "." << temp->data.getcompany() << "\tCHARGE: " << temp->data.getcharge() << endl;
        temp = temp->next;
        i++;
    }

}
```

The main :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Header1.h"
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    list<account> A;
    account acc;
    //int x;
    while (true)
    {
        int choice, choice2, i , m, d;
        string n, p;

        cout << "*** Welcome to ASU Bank ***" << endl;
        cout << "|-------------------------|" << endl;
        cout << "| 1. Get a New Account    |" << endl;
        cout << "| 2. Open My Account      |" << endl;
        cout << "| 3. Statistics           |" << endl;
        cout << "|-------------------------|" << endl;

        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "Please enter your Name: ";
            cin >> n;
            cout << "\n Please enter your Password: ";
            cin >> p;
            acc.pushaccount(n, p);
            A.add(acc);
            A.printaccounts();
            break;

        case 2:
            cout << "-Please enter your Name: ";
            cin >> n;
            cout << "\n -Please enter your Password: ";
            cin >> p;

            if (A.checkaccount(n, p))
            {
                acc = A.getaccount(n, p);
                list<card> C;
                list<transaction> T;
                card c;
                transaction t;

                while (true)
                {

                    cout << "\n|-------------------------|" << endl;
                    cout << "| 1. Get a New Card       |" << endl;
                    cout << "| 2. Make Transaction     |" << endl;
                    cout << "| 3. Print Transactions   |" << endl;
                    cout << "| 4. Pay                  |" << endl;
                    cout << "| 5. Companies Record     |" << endl;
                    cout << "| 6. Get Balance          |" << endl;
                    cout << "| 7. Main Menu            |" << endl;
                    cout << "|-------------------------|" << endl;
                    cin >> choice2;
                    switch (choice2)
                    {
                    case 1:
                        //ba2a ye3ml cards with different ids and push them in the list YEAY :D
                        acc.setcard();
                        C = acc.getclist();
                        C.printcards();
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        cout << "-Please enter your card ID: ";
                        cin >> i;
                        cout << "\n -Please enter your card Password: ";
                        cin >> p;
                        if (C.checkcard(i, p))
                        {
                            //bey3ml add fy list gedida w mesh bey7seb balance..same error
                            c = C.getcard(i, p);
                            c.settrans();
                            c.getlist().printtransactions();

                        }
                        else cout << "Invalid Entery !\n";
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        cout << "-Please enter your card ID: ";
                        cin >> i;
                        cout << "\n -Please enter your card Password: ";
                        cin >> p;
                        if (acc.getclist().checkcard(i, p))
                        {
                            c = acc.getclist().getcard(i, p);
                            c.getlist().printtransactions();


                        }
                        else cout << "Invalid Entery !\n";
                        break;

                    case 4:





                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
            else
                cout << "The Account doesn't exist please check your info.\n";

            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Edited part:
1. changed all the data in node class to pointer to data

2.

```
card * list<T>::getcard(int i, string p)
{
    node <T> * temp = head;
    card* c;
    while (temp != nullptr)
    {
        if (temp->data.getid() == i && temp->data.getpassword() == p)
        {
            c = temp;
            return &c;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return &c;
}
```

solved part is that there is a transaction list with different transactions saved in it but the account list and card list have the problem:
if I add john to the accounts and then joe
it will have two accounts with the name joe.
and same problem with cards list

Comment: Because `getcard` returns a _copy_ of the `card` instead of a pointer or reference to it.

Comment: but I used the get functions in the code when I was making  new accounts, and new cards for the same account, and it worked .. by everytime I issue a new card to the account it is saved.

Comment: The transactions are only saved in the _copy_ of the card, not in the card managed by the account object.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious can you please check the edited part ?